Are homotheties the algebra of a Lie group?
Is the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{s}(n)$ of homotheties of $\mathfrak{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ the Lie algebra associated (being the tangent space at the point $1$) to a particular Lie group?

What is $\mathfrak{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Yes, of $G=S(n)=\exp \mathfrak{s}(n)$.
